# What is going on with the textboxes in our login pages?

Tags: bug, login

[image]

This is an iPhone 5s running mobile safari.  Reproducible on other sites?  It happened when I clicked the textbox for email.

Comment: Well, mobile devices are not officially supported on the full layout. The fact that Area 51 doesn't *have* a mobile layout doesn't change the fact.

Comment: @animuson still, there's a difference between broken layout (which is kinda expected) and broken functionality (which shouldn't be the case).

Comment: @JanDvorak Not really. Both the layout *and* functionality are built to be compatible with desktop browsers, not mobile browsers. The JavaScript that operates the pages is just as likely to be incompatible.